# Add string to phrase Javascript

Tags: javascript, string

I'm not sure i'm going bonkers or something. I just can't get my head around this.
I'm currently studying Python, PHP and Javascript and I'm not sure if I mix the syntaxes or anything.
Anyhow, I'm going to have a function that adds a string to a phrase. My string is 'grey' and the end result should be 'My favorite color is grey' So the code should be like 'My favorite color is' + 'grey'.
The code I have so far is:

```
function stringPhrase(); {
document.write ("grey");
}
var result = ("My favorite color is" + stringPhrase());
```

Am I anyway near the correct syntax or am I heading in the wrong direction?
Thanks a plenty.
Regards, Thomas

Comment: You can't concatenate the result of a `document.write()` with something else. What's written, is already written.

Answer (score 3):

You are heading in the wrong direction.. This is how you should use functions:

```
function stringPhrase() {
  return "grey";
}
var result = "My favorite color is " + stringPhrase();
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
function stringPhrase() {
  return 'grey';
}
var result = 'My favorite color is'+stringPhrase();
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that your `stringPhrase` function is not doing what you expect. What you want that function to do is simply *return* the appropriate string: 'grey'.

So your function should look something like this:

```
function stringPhrase() {
  return "grey";
}
```

You can now use the same code you had before to call the function and get it's return value concatenated to another string:

```
var result = "My favorite color is" + stringPhrase();
```

The [`document.write` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write) actually writes content to the page - this is not what you want as it can easily remove any other code (HTML or scripts) that you currently have on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Your telling the document to write something in the function. Once it's written you can't append to it.

Use this;

```
function stringPhrase() {
   return 'grey'; 
}

var result = ("My favorite color is" + stringPhrase());
```